# How to implement auto iterators correctly

Tags: c++, auto

I decided to replace

```
for (auto messageIterator = message.begin(); messageIterator != message.end(); ++messageIterator)
```

with

```
for (auto &messageIterator : message)
```

and it works. Then I decided to apply similar approach to this loop

```
for (auto alphabetIterator = alphabet.begin(), rotorIterator = rotor.begin(); alphabetIterator != alphabet.end(), rotorIterator != rotor.end(); ++alphabetIterator, ++rotorIterator)
```

and my code looks like this but it doesn't work.

```
for (auto &alphabetIterator : alphabet, &rotorIterator : rotor)
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: It just doesn't work this way. I think boost has a class that can combine two iterators, or you write your own wrapper class.

Comment: The "similar approach" is only valid if `alphabet` and `rotor` are the same types (e.g. vectors with the same type of elements) since `auto` deduction can only resolve to a single type.   The last example (of what "your code looks like") is not valid

Comment: The condition `alphabetIterator != alphabet.end(), rotorIterator != rotor.end()` does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: @Peter Yes, I have 2 strings with the same number of characters. I know that my last example doesn't work that's why I'm asking for help

Comment: @molbdnilo I think it makes my loop work until the end of alphabet and rotor reached. Am I wrong?

Comment: @haierophanto It means the same as `rotorIterator != rotor.end()`. The comma is not a logical connective; you're looking for `&&`.

Answer (score 2):

With range-v3, you might do:

```
std::vector<int> vi{1, 2, 3};
std::vector<std::string> vs{"one", "two", "three"};

for (const auto& [i, s] : ranges::view::zip(vi, vs)) {
    std::cout << i << " " << s << std::endl;   
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c368e84ce234250)